# jQuery: click add to array and save as cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, jquery-isotope

I have a function set up with the jQuery cookie plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie, with the click function on `.grid-block` it stores each `data-hook` in an array, saves them as a cookie, then these chosen divs are viewable on the `/itin/your-itin/` page. Here's a demo I've set up too: http://nealfletcher.co.uk/itin/ If you click on the `.grid-block` divs, this will add them to your itinerary, then when you navigate to: http://nealfletcher.co.uk/itin/your-itin/ only these divs are viewable and stored as a cookie for x amount of time. This works great, BUT if I then go back to add more divs, these are stored as a cookie, but the previous ones are wiped, I want to keep appending to the array, store it as a cookie, then when you navigate to: http://nealfletcher.co.uk/itin/your-itin/ it will display all your selections, even if they've been added separately. If that makes sense? 
jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function () {

    var cfilter = [];

    var $container = $('.block-wrap');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.grid-block',
            animationEngine: 'best-available',
            filter: '.grid-block',
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: 151
            }
        });


        $(".grid-block").click(function () {

            var thing = $(this).attr("data-hook");
            var test = "." + thing;

            cfilter.push(test);

            $.removeCookie('listfilter', {
                path: '/itin/your-itin/'
            });

            // We need to set the cookie only once
            // it stays at the url for 7 days
            $.cookie("listfilter", cfilter, {
                expires: 365,
                path: '/itin/your-itin/'
            });

        });


        if ($.cookie("listfilter") !== 'null') {
            // console log just for testing
            console.log($.cookie());
            $('.block-wrap').isotope({
                filter: $.cookie("listfilter")
            });
            return false;
        } else {
            // !! this part could be refactored
            // as you don't really need to check against the url
            // when the cookie doesn't exist show all elements
            $('.block-wrap').isotope({
                filter: ''
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will need to load the cookie in the first page. As it is now, you're simply overwriting it, instead of loading and adding to it.

Comment: @RenéRoth ah I see, how do you think I'd go about doing this then?

Comment: Added my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `var cfilter = [];` to `var cfilter = $.cookie("listfilter");`

This way you load the changed cookie and add to it instead of overwriting it.

Better code practice would be to check if the cookie exists before using it though, but you get my hint.

You made an error in implementing my change:

```
 if ($.cookie("listfilter") !== 'null') {
                var cfilter = [];
            } else {
                var cfilter = $.cookie("listfilter");
            }
```

is wrong, use

```
 if ($.cookie("listfilter")) {
                var cfilter =  $.cookie("listfilter");
            } else {
                var cfilter =[];
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I have tried this, still no luck though, updated link: http://nealfletcher.co.uk/itin/ and the itinerary page: http://nealfletcher.co.uk/itin/your-itin/ still if you refresh `/itin/` and add more, the `itin/your-itin` are still being replaced with the new ones and not appending the additional

Comment: Could you change the variable to a global for easier debugging?

Comment: still no luck I'm afraid :( updated link: http://nealfletcher.co.uk/itin/ add some blocks, refresh the: http://nealfletcher.co.uk/itin/your-itin/ page, these blocks are displayed, thats fine. Refresh http://nealfletcher.co.uk/itin/ to add more, then when you go back to http://nealfletcher.co.uk/itin/your-itin/ it is only displaying your new selection and not a combination of both